# d3 data parse/convert (from long to wide)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dataformat

I have a dataset that looks like this in csv format:

```
continents  countries   values
Europe  Germany 20
Europe  France  30
Europe  Spain   40
Asia    Singapore   100
Asia    Japan   300
Asia    China   30
Asia    Tiwan   500
America USA 50
America Canada  35
America Brazil  30
America Equador 14
```

When I parse it using `d3.csv` and `map` then the data looks like this:

```
[
{continents: "Europe", countries: "Germany", values: 20}
{continents: "Europe", countries: "France", values: 30} 
{continents: "Europe", countries: "Spain", values: 40} and so forth. ]
```

What I'd like to do is to convert the format into wide one by continents group, so that the data looks like this

```
[
{continents: "Europe", 
    values: {"Germany" : 20},
            {"France" : 30},
            {"Spain" : 40}},
{continents: "Asia",
    values: {"Singapore" : 100},
            {"Japan" : 300},
            {"China" : 30}}
]
```

That's how I'm doing at the moment.

```
d3.csv("/data/data.csv").then(function(csv) { 
    data = csv.map(function(d) {
        return {
            continents: d.continents,
            countries: d.countries,
            values: +d.values}
    });
```

The format doesn't need to be exactly the same like the example above but the point is to make key:value pairs with country and values which belong to their respective continents group.

Could anyone let me know how to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to use `d3.nest`**

[`d3.nest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/v1.0.7/README.md#nests) is d3's object for grouping data. You can use it to get you most of the way and then perform a quick transformation afterward:

```
var groups = d3.nest().key(d => d.continents).entries(rows),
    result = groups.map(function(d){
    return {
        continents: d.key,
        values: d.values
  };
```

This will produce something like:

```
[{"continents":"Europe",
  "values":[
    {"continents":"Europe","countries":"Germany","values":"20"}, ...
  ],
 },
 {"continents":"Asia",
  "values": [...]
 }, ... ]
```

**Alternative: use`d3.group`**

Another way you can get most of the way there is using [`d3.group`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#group), which is part of [`d3-array`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#group):

```
var groups = Array.from(d3.group(rows, d => d.continents));
```

You can then use these `groups` to get the object you wanted:

```
groups.map(function(d){
    return {
    continents: d[0],
      values: d[1]
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi @mdml, thank you for your answer. It seemed making sense and I tried but continuosly I got an error that "TypeError: d3.group is not a function". Do you happen to have any idea about this error?

Comment: on top of the quesion above, could you suggest some workaround in case the d3.group doesn't work for me? some pure JS should be also fine.

Comment: @Jamie: I've updated to use `d3.nest`, since `d3.group` is only part of `d3-array`.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. That really helped me understand it. That's what I was looking for. I just have one more question, what if the data is nested two levels by two groups? For example, there is one more col, gender, and the data is nested by continent and country. Then, how the map would work to have the same format,

{continent : { 
country: 
{ 
male: value,
female: value}}}

Comment: I suggest you ask as a different question, though if I understand right it seems like you could just use two keys.